# SWT/RCP bypass modal dialog

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Is it possible to ignore an SWT dialog's modality when it is raised?

The issue is that I have an Eclipse RCP application which can be displayed on multiple (8+ screens) at any given time; there can be a single modal dialog raised somewhere on any of the screens (i.e. a user clicks on the Help->About Eclipse page, which displays a modal dialog) which blocks/freezes the rest of the screens until the user finds it and closes it. This is quite problematic as it can be hidden somewhere among a mess of other GUIs.

**Ideally it should be possible to interact with the rest of the GUI dialogs even though there is a modal dialog open somewhere. Is this possible?**

The cleanest solution is to set the dialog to be non modal (of course) either when setting its style or by invoking the setBlockOnOpen(false); method on the configureShell(...). Unfortunately this is not an option, as the application uses built in eclipse plugins, which are set to modal by default. Is there a way to set it non blocking after it has been opened?

You can also force the modal dialog into the viewport via shell.forceActive(), however this is an ugly solution as it also brings the root swt window into view. If there is a way to just bring forward the modal dialog without its parent, this would be an ok solution.

SWT.shell is quite limited, but maybe there is some other way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: `setBlockOnOpen` is not an alternative to the shell style, it just determines if the dialog `open` method returns immediately or waits for OK/Cancel to be pressed. It is only the shell style that determines the modality, styles can't be changed once to dialog is opened.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for this useful piece of information, doesn't solve the original problem though, I am aware that the style cant be changed on open, but there must be a way to ignore it, no?

Comment: Why would there be a way to ignore the style? A dialog that is designed to be application modal might not work correctly if it is not app modal. The standard JFace dialogs don't provide any way to override the style specified by the dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 So what you're essentially saying is that I'm in limbo with regards to this problem...